# Can wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk support window.confirm?

Tags: webkit

I'm running [wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk](https://snapcraft.io/wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk) in [ubuntu-frame](https://mir-server.io/ubuntu-frame) on Ubuntu 22.04.

I have a form using `window.confirm` to show a confirmation dialog. e.g. `confirm("Are you sure?");`. When running in ubuntu-frame the dialog is never shown and always returns false preventing the form submission.

`wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk.list-websettings` shows `--allow-modal-dialogs=BOOL` as an option. I'm not sure how to set this to enable wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk or ubuntu-frame to show the confirmation dialog.

I've tried `sudo snap set wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk allow-modal-dialogs=true` but that doesn't help.